# Adding a custom SOAP header using c#

Tags: c#

I have created a proxy class in c# using `Wsdl.exe` from the WSDL structure.

I need to serialize the proxy class and send to an `HttpWebRequest`.

This is the code I used to serialize the class

```
using (System.IO.Stream soapStream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\SoapFormat.xml", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
   System.Xml.Serialization.SoapReflectionImporter soapRefImp = new System.Xml.Serialization.SoapReflectionImporter();
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping xmlTypeMapping = soapRefImp.ImportTypeMapping(typeof(clsPerson));
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSerializer =
      new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(xmlTypeMapping);
   xmlSerializer.Serialize(soapStream, p);
}
```

I am getting the xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<clsPerson xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="id1">
  <FirstName xsi:type="xsd:string">Jeff</FirstName>
  <MI xsi:type="xsd:string">A</MI>
  <LastName xsi:type="xsd:string">Price</LastName>
</clsPerson>
```

I need to add soap envelope. how can i add in c#.

My output should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
<clsPerson xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="id1">
      <FirstName xsi:type="xsd:string">Jeff</FirstName>
      <MI xsi:type="xsd:string">A</MI>
      <LastName xsi:type="xsd:string">Price</LastName>
    </clsPerson>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Do u need to create a string builder and add the soap envelope as string.
then insert the xml into that string.

for eg

```
string s= "<body>"+ xml  + "</body">
```

Any other option in c# to create soap envelope?

I need to send this soapenvelope to a webservice as httprequest.

Any helps appreciated.

this requires webservice not wcf.

thanks

supriya

Comment: WCF **IS** web services......

Comment: i will politely accept the answers if anything provided and that will solve my problem.

Comment: @marc_s Incorrect.  Unless the WCF service is using SOAP it is not by definition a web service.